# Prevent Slack from sending requests after each radio button click

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I have a form with multiple inputs on Slack.
Radio buttons appear to work as 'Submit' buttons.

I want to send the form at the end when pressing the Submit button.

Code example:

```
{
"blocks": [
    {
        "type": "section",
        "text": {
            "type": "mrkdwn",
            "text": "Section block with radio buttons"
        },
        "accessory": {
            "type": "radio_buttons",
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Option1",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-0"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Option2",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-1"
                }
            ],
            "action_id": "radio_buttons-action"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "actions",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "button",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Submit",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "value": "click_me_123",
                "action_id": "actionId-0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**How can I disable radio buttons from acting as submit buttons?**

Comment: What do you mean by "appear to work as 'Submit' buttons" ? I really don't think code for submit button is triggered for this

Comment: A request to our backend is being triggered.  Apparently, this is the default behavior and cannot be changed. I got an answer from their support team. I'll post it an answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from Slack's support team. Apparently, it's impossible to turn off this behavior at this moment.

Slack's support team:

> When a user makes use of an interactive component in a modal, that
> will always dispatch a block_actions payload. This is described here:
> https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#payloads This is designed
> to accommodate error handling and dynamic adjustments to a modal
> before submission.
>
> It's not possible to turn this off, but you can safely ignore any
> block_actions payloads and just process the view_submission payload
> once you receive that.